# Booleans and submitting

Tags: php

My code in php isn't working as planned. The problem is, It won't do all the lines in:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
The goal of this code is to be able to edit your account information. There is another strange thing which might be relevant to it. The code in:

```
if (!$edit){
}
```

will always be on the screen. For example if I put in echo 'hello'; It will still show even if the boolean is true. I would love to know what the problem is and I am asking your help. Here is my code:

```
$edit=false;
echo
<<<EOT
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<input name="edit" type="submit" value="edit"></td>
</form>
EOT;
if (!$edit){
//some action
}
if ( isset( $_POST['edit'] ) ) { 
$edit=true;

    if($edit==true){
echo'<table>';
echo
<<<EOT
  <form action="profile.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="about" rows="5" cols="50" >{$about}</textarea> 
  <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></td>
  </form>
EOT;
echo'</table>';
        if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
            $sql_result = $mysqli->query("update account_information SET about='".$about."' WHERE username = '".$username."'");
            $edit=false;
        }
}
}
```

***EDIT:***

I want to only show the **EDIT** button at first, when I press the edit button, the **Submit** button and **Textarea** will be availabe. I want the edit button to dissappear once I clicked it. Afterwards I type something in the textarea and click the submit button which will lead to the text of the textarea to show on the screen and insert in my database.

Comment: *Is* `$_POST['submit']` set?  Dump `$_POST` or use your browser to inspect the Request parameters.

Comment: Is the PHP code display on your screen literally? Or how do you mean?

Comment: Everything that comes back during your post/get is a string, so keep that in mind when writing your code.  Using  if ($value)  only checks if $value has a value, therefore "false" returns true because "false" is a string, not a boolean.

Comment: @AmalMurali You mean the if (!$edit){
}? No everything between it will be on the screen.

Comment: What if you only declare $edit at the top of the page, and no where else? Like this: $edit = isset( $_POST['edit'] ) ? true : false;

Comment: @Dr.Flink I dont quite exactly know what you mean? The $edit changes everytime when a button is clicked.

Comment: No, it does not :). Your if-statement about $_POST['submit'] is set will never be reached because of it is beeing preceded by the if-statement about $_POST['edit']. The script won't remember what value was stored in $edit when submiting the next form ($_POST['edit'] will no longer be set, only $_POST['submit']).

Comment: @Dr.Flink Aha I see what you mean and what's going wrong but I dont know why it does that and how to solve it.

Comment: @loko: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you please edit the question and add the expected workflow of your script? I think it's confusing, TBH.

Comment: Lift out the "if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {...}" -part to follow the "if ( isset( $_POST['edit'] ) ) {...}", instead of having it inside/nested.

Comment: @loko: Sure. I've posted an answer below. See if that helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a structural error, try something like this instead:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['edit'] ) ) {
    // Print out the edit form
} else if ( isset( $_POST['edit'] ) ) {
    // Update database
} else {
<<<EOT
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<input name="edit" type="submit" value="edit"></td>
</form>
EOT;
}
```

Comment: Please, see my edit of the code. The edit form is the form with the textarea.

Comment: It gives me this error:Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given, but it does insert it in the database

Comment: Well, in other words -the solution is correct. The error you're mentioning is a proof of that... Can't understand why you are voting me down! :'(

Comment: Ah, sorry! Thought it was you breaking my heart :P

Comment: Now I'm happy again! :D

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
      `<input name="edit" type="submit" value="edit">`
```

to

```
  ` <input name="submit" type="submit" value="edit">`
```

the attribute `name` needs to be added so that server can render form data but you are using `submit` that is invaild